# Admin SDK Drive Activity Log doc_title partial matches?

Tags: filter, google-admin-sdk

I'm using the Google Admin SDK to query the Drive Activity Log using the following URL as the basis for the query:

https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive?maxResults=1000&filters=doc_title==Design

It successfully finds documents whose title is "Design".  But I'm trying to query for documents whose titles contain the word "Design" (like it does in the Admin GUI.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  (I'd rather not just query everything, then filter on my side if possible)

Comment: Any chance you could show a more complete example of how you're sending that query? The docs leave me scratching my head with that approach (I understand more how to use gapi.clients in JS) and I suspect I need it because I can't get any results using gapi.client.reports.activities.list (trying to get folder rename activity).

Answer (score 0):

No, as per the reference documentation there is no filter operator for "contains" matching:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list#filters